Can't get cognito:groups from x-amzn-oidc-data
I have an alb configured to work with cognito user pool.
Reading the token provided the the alb in the x-amzn-oidc-data header, I can't find the cognito:groups claim.
It is provided in the x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken tho.
nginx:
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-scope: 'email openid aws.cognito.signin.user.admin profile'

aws cognito:

The claims after verifying the token are:
{:sub ***, :email_verified false, :identities [{"dateCreated":"1730640953221","userId":"***","providerName":"Google","providerType":"Google","issuer":null,"primary":"true"}], :email ***, :username ***, :exp 1731006113, :iss https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/***}

Am I missing a configuration or should I just read and verify the access token?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#user-claims-encoding
